# creating all day events in google scripts

Tags: events, google-apps-script, outlook, google-calendar-api

I am working for an organization that has an outlook calendar that everyone in the office needs to access.  We are starting to switch over to IPhones and to be able to let our users access that calendar I am sharing the events with a google calendar that users with Iphones can look at.  However, when sharing events with a google calendar from outlook it makes the events go from 12am to 12am and the event takes up the entire day and its hard to see what other events are happening that day.

I have tried to write a few google scripts that convert any google calendar event that is longer than 12 hours into a an "all day event," making the event only show up along the top.

Can I write a google script that says something along the line of:

IF longer than 12 hours SETasALLdayEvent() ???

would you please make suggestions on how I can improve the following google script?  I greatly appreciate it, thanks!

```
function processInvites2() {
  var calendarId =  'examplecalendar@gmail.com'; // this needs to be the email address of the calendar you're monitoring
  var invited = "INVITED";
  var accepted = "YES";
  var accept = CalendarApp.GuestStatus.YES;
  var reject = CalendarApp.GuestStatus.NO;
  var rejection = "Eep - someone else has a booking then..."; //subject line for our email to reject a booking

  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

  var start = new Date();
  var end = new Date("January 1, 2015 00:00:00 UTC");
  var invites = calendar.getEvents(start, end, invited); //find all future invites (up to 2099)

  for(var i = 0; i < invites.length; i++){



      invites[i].setMyStatus(accept);


  }
};
```

Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can write such script. Look at calendarApp.

Comment: Does google scripts have a format that must be used when identifying time in hours? 'IF (e.hour > 12);'? Also, when using the SETasALLdayEvent() do you know of a shortcut to make it only go to the first day? Current it displays as 12am to 12am so even when it changes to an all day event it shows but for two days. I'm surprised that more people haven't run into this issue.

Comment: gas being javascript it uses the standard javascript Date(), plus some date formatting in Utilities.

Comment: Would you mind making suggestions on how to edit a time range in google script?  I have posted what i have been trying to make work.